# Assembly procedure using regbank

Tags: assembly, procedure, dosbox

I read that I can specify to procedures in assembly a registers bank which it will automatically add push (registers) at the beginning and pop (registers) at the end (before ret).
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/a166/a166_st_proc.htm

But I couldn't find it anywhere else or examples of people who use it.

So, can I actually use it? That's looks weird to me and I never saw it in real code. Would like to hear answers based on experiences.

I'm using dosbox if it matter. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you're reading the wrong documentation. Not all assemblers are alike.

The Keil documentation you linked is for the Keil A166 Assembler, which targets [certain Infineon and ST microcontrollers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C166_family). It is completely irrelevant to the x86 processor emulated by DOSBox.

Comment: I'm asking if there is similar thing in x86. I couldn't find any doc for "proc" in x86

Comment: Not really. The register banking functionality described in the documentation is specific to those microcontrollers.